# Why does getComputedStyle() in a JEST test return different results to computed styles in Chrome / Firefox DevTools

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've written a custom button (`MyStyledButton`) based on **material-ui** `Button`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    minWidth: 100
  }
});

function MyStyledButton(props) {
  const buttonStyle = useStyles(props);
  const { children, width, ...others } = props;

  return (

      <Button classes={{ root: buttonStyle.root }} {...others}>
        {children}
      </Button>
     );
}

export default MyStyledButton;
```

It is styled using a theme and this specifies the `backgroundColor` to be a shade of yellow (Specficially `#fbb900`)

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export const myYellow = "#FBB900";

export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      containedPrimary: {
        color: "black",
        backgroundColor: myYellow
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The component is instantiated in my main `index.js` and wrapped in the `theme`.

```
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <MyStyledButton variant="contained" color="primary">
       Primary Click Me
     </MyStyledButton>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
```

If I examine the button in Chrome DevTools the `background-color` is "computed" as expected. This is also the case in Firefox DevTools.

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

However when I write a JEST test to check the `background-color` and I query the DOM node style òf the button using `getComputedStyles()` I get `transparent` back and the test fails.

```
const wrapper = mount(
    <MyStyledButton variant="contained" color="primary">
      Primary
    </MyStyledButton>
  );
  const foundButton = wrapper.find("button");
  expect(foundButton).toHaveLength(1);
  //I want to check the background colour of the button here
  //I've tried getComputedStyle() but it returns 'transparent' instead of #FBB900
  expect(
    window
      .getComputedStyle(foundButton.getDOMNode())
      .getPropertyValue("background-color")
  ).toEqual(myYellow);
```

**I've included a CodeSandbox with the exact problem, the minimum code to reproduce and the failing JEST test.**

[image: Edit headless-snow-nyofd]

Comment: .MuiButtonBase-root-33 background-color is transparent while .MuiButton-containedPrimary-13 is not - so problem is, classes in CSS are equaly important, so only load order distinguish them --> in test styles are loaded in wrong order.

Comment: @Andreas - Updated as requested

Comment: @Zyndar - Yes I know that. Is there any way to get this test to pass ?

Comment: Wouldn't the `theme` need to be used in the test? As in, wrap the `<MyStyledButton>` in the `<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>`? Or use some wrapper function to add the theme to all components?

Comment: No that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: if the point of @Zydnar is still valid, try to fix that - by giving it more importance(e.g. by doubling the class selector) or load it in the same order.

Comment: @inetphantom - Can you provide an example please ?

Comment: If `.myclass` is overwritten by `.otherclass` you can create a rule like `.myclass.myclass` that then is more specific than `.otherclass`.

Comment: This may has to do with cascading issue of styles in jsdom: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8464

Answer (score 3):

I've gotten closer, but not quite at a solution yet.

The main issue is that MUIButton injects a  tag to the  element to power the styles. This isn't happening in your unit test. I was able to get this to work by using the [createMount](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/test-utils/createMount.js) that the material tests use.

After this fix, the style is correctly showing up. However, the computed style still doesn't work. It looks like others have run into issues with enzyme handling this correctly - so I'm not sure if it's possible.

To get to where I was, take your test snippet, copy this to the top, and then change your test code to:

```
const myMount = createMount({ strict: true });
  const wrapper = myMount(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyStyledButton variant="contained" color="primary">
        Primary
      </MyStyledButton>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
```

```
class Mode extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    /**
     * this is essentially children. However we can't use children because then
     * using `wrapper.setProps({ children })` would work differently if this component
     * would be the root.
     */
    __element: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    __strict: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    // Excess props will come from e.g. enzyme setProps
    const { __element, __strict, ...other } = this.props;
    const Component = __strict ? React.StrictMode : React.Fragment;

    return <Component>{React.cloneElement(__element, other)}</Component>;
  }
}

// Generate an enhanced mount function.
function createMount(options = {}) {

  const attachTo = document.createElement('div');
  attachTo.className = 'app';
  attachTo.setAttribute('id', 'app');
  document.body.insertBefore(attachTo, document.body.firstChild);

  const mountWithContext = function mountWithContext(node, localOptions = {}) {
    const strict = true;
    const disableUnnmount = false;
    const localEnzymeOptions = {};
    const globalEnzymeOptions = {};

    if (!disableUnnmount) {
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(attachTo);
    }

    // some tests require that no other components are in the tree
    // e.g. when doing .instance(), .state() etc.
    return mount(strict == null ? node : <Mode __element={node} __strict={Boolean(strict)} />, {
      attachTo,
      ...globalEnzymeOptions,
      ...localEnzymeOptions,
    });
  };

  mountWithContext.attachTo = attachTo;
  mountWithContext.cleanUp = () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(attachTo);
    attachTo.parentElement.removeChild(attachTo);
  };

  return mountWithContext;
}
```

Comment: Do we have any progress on that, I am also facing the same issue with Material components.